# IoT fault detection algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, iot, error-detection

I am attempting to implement a sensor fault detection algorithm from a white paper I found here: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2013/712028/ref/
My math skills are decent, but this article does not give great detail on how everything is set up.

My current implementation looks something like the following:

```
/*******************************************************************************
How this algorithm works:
    1) There exists W historical windows which hold the distribution objects (mean, variance)
        for that window. Each window is of size m (the sliding window size)
    2) There exists a current window which changes every iteration by popping the 
        oldest value into the buffer window.
    3) There exists a buffer window which takes the oldest values from the current window
        each iteration. Once the buffer window reaches size m
        it then becomes the newest historical window.
*******************************************************************************/

int m = 10; //Statistics sliding window size
float outlierDetectionThreshold; // The outlier detection threshold for sensor s, also called epsilon
List<float> U; // Holds the last 10 windows mean
List<float> V; // Holds the last 10 windows variance
List<float> CurrentWindow; // Holds the last m values

procedure GFD()
    do
        get a value vi 
        Detection(vi)
    while not end
return

procedure Detection(vi)
    init outlierDetectionThreshold
    init U and V, loading last m distribution characteristics from DB
    init CurrentWindow loading the last m - 1 values

    Xi; // What is this?
    Tau; // What is this?

    Insert vi into CurrentWindow // CurrentWindow now has the m latest values 

    float CurrentWindowMean = Mean(CurrentWindow)
    float CurrentWindowVariance = Variance(CurrentWindow)

    if (IsStuck(CurrentWindowVariance) or IsSpikes(vi))
        return
    If (IsOutlier(vi) and not IsRatStatChagne(vi))
        return;
    IsRatStatChagne(vi);
    return

procedure IsStuck(variance)
    if (variance == 0)
        return true;
    return false;

procedure IsSpike(windowMean, windowVariance, historicalMeans, historicalVariances, xi, tau)
    if ( (mean / Mean(historicalMeans)) < xi)
        if ( (variance / Mean(historicalVariances)) > tau)
            return true;
    return false;

procedure IsOutlier(historicalMeans, historicalVariances, outlierDetectionThreshold)
    // use historicalMeans and historicalVariances to calculate theta
    if (theta > outlierDetectionThreshold)
        return true;
```

I am running into difficulty implementing the IsOutlier and IsRatStatChange functions.

1. In IsSpike, how are xi and tau calculated, or what do they represent?
2. For the IsOutlier function, how is theta calculated?
3. For the IsRatStatStange function, I have not looked into as much yet, but does anyone have a solid grasp to write this?

Any other insights you gleam would be most appreciated.
Thanks in advance.